# SASS --watch constantly failing, Deleted template detected

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

I am working on a project in vim, and every time I save my .scss file, I get the following error:

```
Deleted template detected: /home/path/to/my.scss
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/plugin/compiler.rb:338:in `read': No such file or directory - public/stylesheets/my.scss (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/listen-0.4.2/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:34:in `join'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/listen-0.4.2/lib/listen/adapters/linux.rb:34:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/listen-0.4.2/lib/listen/multi_listener.rb:44:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/plugin/compiler.rb:306:in `watch'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/plugin.rb:107:in `send'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/plugin.rb:107:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:431:in `watch_or_update'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:302:in `process_result'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.17/bin/sass:8
        from /usr/bin/sass:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/sass:19
```

Thoughts? It works if I manually restart the --watch server every time, but that's somewhat against the spirit of it.

Comment: same ploblem, but when I delete file. SASS should not crash down, but it is. =(

Answer (score -2):

You should totally use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)!

### What Compass is

Compass is a must-have tool for every SASS coder. Compass consists of two parts:

- a meta-framework for SASS;
- a command line tool used for compiling Compass projects and doing other useful stuff.

The `compass watch` command is exactly what you're looking for. It will recompile the CSS whenever you save a change, just like `sass --watch`. **It will not fail when you delete a SASS/SCSS file**, unless you keep `@import`'ing the deleted file.

### Ridiculously short installation guide

For the following to work, you must have Ruby and [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/pages/download). As you're using the `sass` command line tool, chances are that you already have them both.

To start using Compass, do:

1. Install Compass with RubyGems: `gem install compass`.
2. Create a `compass.rb` file in the root of your project (in your case it's `Project/compass.rb`).
3. Run `compass watch` and start coding.

### Example of a config.rb file

Here's a minimal `compass.rb` that might work for you:

```
css_dir =   "stylesheets"
sass_dir =  "sass"
```